# Python - Dictionary - If loop variable not changing

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, if-statement

Project is about to convert short forms into long description and read from csv file

Example: user enters LOL and then it should response 'Laugh of Laughter'

Expectation: Till the time time user enter wrong keyword computer keep on asking to enter short form and system answers it's long description from CSV file
I considered each row of CSV file as dictionary and broke down into keys and values
logic used: - Used while so, that it keeps on asking until short column didn't finds space, empty cell. But issue is after showing successful first attempt comparison in IF loop is not happening because readitems['short' ] is not getting updated on each cycle

AlisonList.csv Values are:

```
short,long
lol,laugh of laughter
u, you
wid, with
```

```
import csv
from lib2to3.fixer_util import Newline
from pip._vendor.distlib.util import CSVReader
from _overlapped import NULL

READ = "r"
WRITE = 'w'
APPEND = 'a'

# Reading the CSV file and converted into Dictionary

with open ("AlisonList.csv", READ) as csv_file:
    readlist = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    # Reading the short description and showing results

    for readitems in readlist:        
        readitems ['short'] == ' '        
        while readitems['short'] !='' :
            # Taking input of short description            
            smsLang = str(input("Enter SMS Language :  "))
            if smsLang == readitems['short']:
                print(readitems['short'], ("---Means---"), readitems['long'])
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Thanks Ed Ward. Really thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import csv

READ = "r"
WRITE = 'w'
APPEND = 'a'

# Reading the CSV file and converted into Dictionary

with open ("AlisonList.csv", READ) as csv_file:
    readlist = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

    word_lookup = { x['short'].strip() : x['long'].strip() for x in readlist }

while True:
    # Taking input of short description            
    smsLang = str(input("Enter SMS Language :  ")).lower()
    normalWord = word_lookup.get(smsLang.lower())
    if normalWord is not None:
        print(f"{smsLang} ---Means--- {normalWord}")
    else:
        print(f"Sorry, '{smsLang}' is not in my dictionary.")
```

Sample output:

```
Enter SMS Language :  lol
lol ---Means--- laugh of laughter
Enter SMS Language :  u
u ---Means--- you
Enter SMS Language :  wid
wid ---Means--- with
Enter SMS Language :  something that won't be in the dictionary
Sorry, 'something that won't be in the dictionary' is not in my dictionary.
```

Basically, we compile a dictionary from the csv file, using the short words as the keys, and the long words as the items. This allows us in the loop to then just call `word_lookup.get(smsLang)` to find the longer version. If such a key does not exist, we get a result of `None`, so a simple if statement can handle the case where there is no longer version.

Hope this helps.